Remove unused python dependencies inside venv
I've been thinking about a way of cleaning the unnecessary dependencies inside a python virtual machine environment.
I saw different ways of doing this for instance cleaning through Pycharm IDE and installing a package called deptry.
I'm planning to use poetry in further circumstances but if we consider the basic virtual environment is there any sufficient way to clean those unused dependencies?

It's probably easier to just throw it away and create a new one with only the required dependencies.

@chepner actually the problem is I'm copying the requirements.txt along with some code from another directory which it also brings it's dependencies too, I'm thinking about a way to clean those unnecessary dependencies.

If you have a requirements.txt file for your current code, remove the unwanted dependencies from that and use it to create a new virtual environment. "along with some code from another directory". What does that mean? Just add whatever it requires to your requirements.txt file before creating the new venv.

@chepner that would be a good way to resolve this issue but what i'm thinking because you have all list of dependencies in requirements.txt for instance if you delete fastapi, there are still associated dependencies for that
perhaps to uninstall them one by one through terminal like pip uninstall and gets a fresh requirements after that
sorry for taking this too serious or playing it up

Yes, you are taking it too seriously. If requirements.txt changes, just throw away the old environment and create a new one.

@Callme-Milad I'm with you. I have a bloated requirements.txt file. Unused libraries can be in it for many reasons. I want a tool to check my python source and remove all the unused libraries from requirements.txt. I imagine anyone who has run python in a production service has felt some area of this need.
